# cannot alter a table to add foreign key?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Trying to add foreign key on column 'member_id' of projects table which references on primary key 'id' on members table.

Projects Migration

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->text('title');
            $table->text('description');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Members migration

```
Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('country_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->integer('active');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

AddMemberIdToProjects migration

```
Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('member_id');

            $table->foreign('member_id')->references('id')->on('members');

        });
```

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Comment: There's a value present in your column on which you are trying to add foreign key. Truncate both tables snd it'll be going nicely

Comment: The error indicates that problem

Answer (score 1):

Make it `unsigned` and `nullable`.

Separate creating a column and adding foreign key logic to avoid similar errors:

```php
Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {

   $table->unsignedBigInteger('member_id')->nullable();
});

Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->foreign('member_id')->references('id')->on('members');

});
```

Comment: you should not have to separate them, the schema builder should separate them into separate statements if needed